# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Spring Boot error message hidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, http, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, java-11

I've deployed a Spring Boot application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I have implemented @RestControllerAdvice to handle exceptions. The returned HTTP exceptions on the local instance are in the following format

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-03-16T19:28:22.124+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "SOME_MESSAGE",
    "path": "/some/path"
}
```

After I deployed the application the returned error body changed to this

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-03-16T19:30:37.390+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/some/path"
}
```

What can I do to put the message property back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that by default Spring Boot sets

```
server.error.include-message=never;
```

to fix it just set the property to always/on_param

```
server.error.include-message=always;
server.error.include-message=on_param;
```